# How to find the argmax of a two dimensional array in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy ndarray:

```
array = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

Whenever I do, `np.argmax(array)`, it doesn't return a tuple of row and column. 
 Why not?

Answer (score 20):

You didn't specify an `axis`.  It returns an index into the flattened array, [as documented](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html).

```
>>> L = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> np.argmax(L)
8
>>> np.array(L).ravel()[np.argmax(L)]
9
```

If you want to get the row and column from that index, unravel it:

```
>>> np.unravel_index(8, np.array(L).shape)
(2, 2)
```